# Space in Access Control Allow Methods Caused Error

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, laravel-5, response-headers

I ran into an issue which is little strange. The files were migrated on the server long back and were never changed since a month and everything was working fine.

Basically I had this in PHP(I was using laravel framework 5.2) since a month :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
```

The website was working fine and suddenly today it stopped working. I had this error in apache error.log : `Header Access-Control-Allow-Methods contains invalid characters.`

When I removed the space after colon and made like below it worked immediately :

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
```

My concern is :

1. Can this space cause such issue?
2. What could be the reason it was working fine before and same code started throwing error today.
3. I am using AWS EC2 instance and I checked, there were no server/service updates performed, nor any other files were changed.
4. My zend opcache module is disabled, so I am curious if it was cached, what was it for?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error message?  The sole google result for what you typed is your post here suggesting that is not the error message. My understanding, and what I see on RFC 2616, is that space is NOT the issue.  Red Herring?

Comment: A space *before* `:` is very much invalid.  In RFC-2616 *"Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. ... The field value MAY be preceded by any amount of LWS, though a single SP is preferred."*  The space *after* `:` is not an issue but the one before is simply wrong.